# EmberJS - replacing a partial

Tags: ember.js, partial, handlebars.js

So i'm doing a quiz site in EmberJS. I have 3 partial templates which correspond to 3 questions.

in my parent template i have the following:

```
{{partial question1}}
```

which shows the first out of 3 questions. after user answers, i want to replace this with

```
 {{partial question2}}
```

I can think of ways to replace it through jQuery but any ideas to do this in the parent controller/question1's template?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just create one generic question template and simply fill it with the necessary data?

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple questions, it's not the right way to do it with partials.

it would make more sense to:

1) Create a QuestionController

2) Create a template that is bound to that controller and display the question.

In runtime, just change the backend model of the QuestionController to the specific question you would like to display.